# invalid operands to binary expression error

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to write a matrix program in C++ and I get the error invalid operands to binary expression. I know it has to do with my overloaded operator with "*".
In my code main.cpp:

```
Matrix mat7=mat1*3;
cout<<"Mult m1 * 3;"<<endl;
print_matrix(mat7);
```

In this part I am multiplying matrix 1 by 3.

What I need help on is in my matrix.cpp

```
Matrix Matrix::operator * (const Matrix& mat2){
   if(this->num_cols==mat2.num_rows){
       Matrix result(num_rows, mat2.num_cols);
       for(int i=0; i<num_rows; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<mat2.num_cols; j++){
               result.matrix[i][j]=0;
               for(int k=0; k<this->num_cols; k++){
                   result.matrix[i][j]+=matrix[i][k]*mat2.matrix[k][j];
               }
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   else{
       Matrix result(num_rows, num_cols);
       for(int i=0; i<num_rows; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<num_cols; j++){
               result.matrix[i][j]=0;
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
}
```

This for my multiplication operator overload to multiplying another matrix.

My question is how do I do the same but with an integer?

Comment: Make the parameter an `int`?

Comment: Have a look at the following post for what it looks like a decent Matrix implementation: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149669.

Answer (score 0):

I think defining a method `Matrix Matrix::operator* (int factor)` should do what you're looking for.

Comment: This is correct, however it isn't advisable to use a `const` reference on integral values since it's faster to pass by-value in the register, and it won't cause any alias concerns for the compiler